# Check whether array in JSONB column includes any of the values in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**Problem**

Find all records in sample data where `foo->bar` include at least one item from given array e.g. [1,2]

**Sample data**

```
Record 1 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [1,2]
}

Record 2 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [3,4]
}

Record 3 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [5,7]
}

Record 4 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [1]
}

Record 5 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [2,3]
}
```

**Expected result**

```
Record 1 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [1,2]
}


Record 4 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [1]
}

Record 5 => 'foo': {
  'bar': [2,3]
}
```

I tried using operators `@>` and `?|`, the first checks against JSOB and returns only if all items are included. Second has issues with types JSOB => Integer[]

**SQL**

```
SELECT  "some_table".* FROM "some_table" WHERE (foo->'bar' @> '[1,2]'::jsonb);
```

**Rails Scope**

```
scope :for_bar, -> (bars) { where("foo->'bar' @> ?::jsonb", bars.to_json) }
```

Any suggestions to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is:

- extract bar from foo,
- map any element from `bars` to JSON,
- cast the bound values to `array`,
- cast the array of bound values to `jsonb[]`,
- check if `any` of the left JSON values contain the right JSON path/value entries at the top level (`@>`):

```
SomeTable.where("foo->'bar' @> ANY(ARRAY[?]::JSONB[])", [1, 2].map(&:to_s))
```

Comment: Makes total sense, Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `jsonb_array_elements()` to unroll the JSON arrays into sets. Then, in an `EXISTS` subquery, inner join these sets on common elements.

```
SELECT *
       FROM some_table
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM jsonb_array_elements(some_table.foo->'bar') t (v)
                                 INNER JOIN jsonb_array_elements('[1,2]'::jsonb) s (v)
                                            ON t.v = s.v);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=3e49f0e68e15455dffbcbc28642b9dc8)

Answer (score -1):

```
MyTable.where("my_attr->'jsonb_field' @> ANY(ARRAY[?]::JSONB[])", ['Mary'.to_json, 'Jane'.to_json])
```