# Trying to allow for generalized array or value queries like rails uses to allow for where(a: [1]) or where(a: 1) to work and more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

So the data I'm searching for is something like (hundreds of them with various combinations of values):

```
attributes1:
  attr1: "1",
  attr2: "3",
  attr3: ["A,"B"],


attributes2:
  attr1: "2",
  attr2: "5",
  attr3: ["B,"D"],

attributes3:
  attr1: "2",
  attr2: "4",
  attr3: ["B,"D"],
```

I came across this:

[Check whether array in JSONB column includes any of the values in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980659/check-whether-array-in-jsonb-column-includes-any-of-the-values-in-another-array)

Which is close but not quite there (isn't working, unclear why).

A complication though, the queries are predefined and used to populate dropdown menus, so things like `{ attr3: "A", attr2: "4" }` and `{ attr1: ["1", "2"]} }`. Basically very generalized.

I have it working for the easier case of `{ attr1: "2" }` yielding `attributes2` and `attributes3` (or `attr1: '2", attr2: "4"` only giving `attributes3`, but trying to also handle arrays both as an attribute value and as a query value now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use each value from an `attrX:` you can cast it using `Array()`.

```
# Will wrap in an Array
Array("1") => ["1"]

# Will return the original Array
Array(["1"]) => ["1"]
```

Any method that uses that data can be written to always expect an array.